# Sudden permissions problem with SpreadsheetApp.openByID

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The code is supposed to copy some data from another spreadsheet and then I manipulate it.

This code worked yesterday, then I tried adding a library today and now it is still throwing this error even after removing the library and rolling back my code to the version yesterday.

Error Message:

> You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required
>   permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets (line 21,
>   file  "Import")

Code:

```
 data = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1-SyJRflR1YYYYDRo3e7xnDhYYYY6hIGDBKODl9XXXXX').getSheetByName("g1.1").getDataRange().getValues();
```

**I am NOT using "//@OnlyCurrentDoc" anywhere in either of my documents so that is not my problem.**

Google sheets API is turned on for this project, as checked from the resources menu.

The library function I was attempting to use was a simple time one (nothing to do with sheets), and it is not currently being called anywhere in my project and the library has been detached.

Comment: What does you manifest file look like?

Comment: You may need to reauthorize the permissions.  From the code editor, choose a function from the drop down list, and run the function.  If the code is missing a required authorization, you should be prompted with the dialog box to accept the permissions.  If the scopes have been manually set in the appsscript.json file, and the scope for opening a spreadsheet is not present, then you'll never be prompted to authorize the permission, and that error will go on forever.  If you are in an enterprise account, like GSuite, make sure that the domain admin hasn't blocked Spreadsheet services.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Possible Issues:

1. If your library included `//@OnlyCurrentDoc` and you authorized after adding the library, your permissions might've just included the current document.
2. If you had explicitly set scopes[<sup>1</sup>](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes), then those scopes might not have included `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`

#### Possible Solutions:

1. If you want to still use the library, add the `//@NotOnlyCurrentDoc`  in your main script and re-run the function. If not remove the library and re-run your function.

   > [An opposing annotation, @NotOnlyCurrentDoc, is available if your script includes a library that declares @OnlyCurrentDoc, but the master script actually requires access to more than the current file.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization#manual_authorization_scopes_for_sheets_docs_slides_and_forms)
2. Removing the explicit scopes in your  manifest will trigger the normal authorization flow.
3. If all else fails, visit [your account](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions), find your project and remove all access. Now, re-running any function in your script will trigger normal authorization flow.

Comment: Although the library wasn't important, //@NotOnlyCurrentDoc fixed my problem!

Comment: //@NotOnlyCurrentDoc Solved it. Although I don't understand the correct reason. Kindly explain to me.

Comment: At last someone who knows what he is speaking about and doesn't just relate to foggy documentation. Thanks!!!