# Linking standalone google script to sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a specific way how you link standalone google script to sheets ? I've created a web app running from standalone script that links to more than 10 sheets, im trying to reduce the google scopes from showing view all your files to view & manage files in which the script is installed

I've added the standalone script as library to each of the file used but the moment i add

/**

- @OnlyCurrentDoc
  */

to the file the scripts stops working showing error that the user can't call api

[image: Error showed]

All users have edit access to the file and they can open it when then try to do it directly by the URL of the file. I even gave edit access to the main script but it didnt make difference. The script works when i open it but anyone else it throws that error the file is stored on team drive and even users added to the drive are being showed this error

Is there any workaround other than add-on (my company opted out from cloud platform so i can't set Google Cloud Platform (GCP) project required for add-on)

This example of the code that throws the error line 18 is at **var DB = SpreadsheetApp.openById(Log_errors)**

```
    /**
*  Report app usage to logs
*/
function LOG(type, user, argsObject){
// Logs
var Log_analytics = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('Log_analytics');
var Log_errors = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('Log_errors');
var Log_tasks = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('Log_tasks');

switch(type){
    case "pageview":
    var DB = SpreadsheetApp.openById(Log_analytics)
    var LOG = DB.getSheetByName('Views')
    LOG.appendRow([new Date(),user,argsObject[0],argsObject[1],argsObject[2],argsObject[3],argsObject[4],argsObject[5]])
    break;   

    case "exception":
    var DB = SpreadsheetApp.openById(Log_errors)
    var LOG = DB.getSheetByName('Log')
    LOG.appendRow([new Date(),user,argsObject[0],argsObject[1],argsObject[2],argsObject[3],argsObject[4],argsObject[5]])
    break;   

    case "event":
    var DB = SpreadsheetApp.openById(Log_analytics)
    var LOG = DB.getSheetByName('Events')
    LOG.appendRow([new Date(),user,argsObject[0],argsObject[1],argsObject[2],argsObject[3],argsObject[4]])
    break;  

    case "task":
    var DB = SpreadsheetApp.openById(Log_tasks)
    var LOG = DB.getSheetByName('Tasks')
    LOG.appendRow([new Date(),user,argsObject[0],argsObject[1],argsObject[2],argsObject[3],argsObject[4],argsObject[5]])
    break;   
    default: return null  
  }
}

/**
*  Record report generation
*/
function NEW_report(ID,type,link,color,title,msg,location,avatar){
var DB = SpreadsheetApp.openById(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('DB_BACKEND'))
var TAB = DB.getSheetByName('DB_reports')

var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()
var user = username(email)
var timestamp = new Date()

TAB.appendRow([type,color,title,msg,avatar,user,timestamp,link,ID,location])
}
```

This how manifest is showed

[image]

Scopes looks correctly as it shows vie & manage sheets where script is installed

Comment: You're trying to manager those 10 sheets using this webapp?  did you deployed this webapp as execute as user accessing the webapp settings? did all the user have access to all sheets you're managing?

Comment: Yes, file is set to execute as user accessing the app, all files are set that anyone within domain have edit rights to them.  Yes there is a lot of information going by specific location so there is one file for each location plus files tracking loging files tracking who accessed the web app what was changed etc So the standalone script acts as ui showing information from the file that user should be able to see

Comment: See if this can help you :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54655563/sudden-permissions-problem-with-spreadsheetapp-openbyid

Comment: Are the scopes on the manifest file for the library? Could you share a minimal reproducible example of it?

Comment: Service - Add Spreadsheet service. Then authorize.

Comment: Tried this but unfortunately it didn't helped. The wierd thing is that where everything worked fine for me and team members from team drive where the script file stored anyone else was still getting the same error the moment when I remove currentdoconly or add not at beginning it was working fine even when they got edit rights for the files

Comment: Can you clarify the last comment? Apologies for not understanding it.

Comment: Apologies for late reply been on sick leave for few months. What did I mean is that we have a team drive where all files used by script are located in. For any team member that is added as member of that drive everything is working no matter what settings are in the script scopes, even if I add @OnlyCurrentDoc. But for anyone else with whom the files where shared or being accessed through general access set from sharing options it will not work showing the error message.